# Issue aligning elements at center

Tags: html, css

Im trying to align my elements at center but I´m having some problems in this process. I aligned the "Title"  at center and it works, and now I´m doing the same process to other elements but its not working.

Anyone there can see what is wrong? Thank you!

**My jsfiddle with the problem:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mibb/6SLa5/

**My Html**:

```
<section id="loop-news-container">
    <article id="loop-news">
         <a href="#"></a>
         <h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
         <span>Date of Post</span> 
         <img src="image1.jpg" /> 
         <p>Post of 1 <a class="buttonl" href="#show" id="verfancy">read more</a></p></p>
    </article>
```

**My css:**

```
#loop-news-container{width:100%; height:auto; float:left;}
#loop-news{width:280px; height:250px; background:#fff; margin:5px auto 5px auto;}
#loop-news h1 {font-family:'bariol_boldbold';   text-align:center; font-family:'bariol_boldbold';margin:0 auto 0 auto; background:#F00;position:relative; text-decoration:none;}
#loop-news h1 a{text-decoration:none; font-size:20px; color:#002e5e; font-weight:100; }
#loop-news span{font-family:'bariolthin';font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;color:#888;margin:0 auto 0 auto; text-align:center; background-color:#FF0; }
```

Comment: Which elements specifically are you trying to center? Just the `<span>`?

Comment: I want to align all the elements to the center. I already did the title but with other elements its not working and i dont understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of the `<h1>` can be centered with `text-align:center` because it takes the whole width of its container (it's a block-level element). The `<span>`, not so much, as it only takes the width of its content (it's an inline element) - your coloured background make this quite visible. In fact, basically every child element you have there (other than the `<h1>`) is an inline or inline-block element, so applying `text-align:center` to them directly won't work.

If you wanted to center *all* the elements in `#loop-news`, just adding this style would do it:

```
#loop-news {
    text-align:center;
}
```

This causes all inline content of `#loop-news` to be centered. Note that this also renders `text-align:center` on the `<h1>` unnecessary.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SLa5/1/) to show you what this does. If this isn't what you wanted though, let me know and I'll be happy to help further.